# How can generate a Local Server in Ruby

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, server, local

I want to generate *( i dont like create word)* a local server (like localhost/8000) on my LAN by Ruby, i researched İnternet but i cant make it.
My aim is showing html pages in local servers , using by Ruby.
How can i make it?

```
require 'socket'
```

I'm using **socket** in Standart Library but it gives error when I refresh page.

```
require 'socket' 
server = TCPServer.new('localhost', 2345)
loop do
  socket = server.accept
  request = socket.gets
  STDERR.puts request
  response = "Hello World!\n"
  socket.print "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n" +
           "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n" +
           "Content-Length: #{response.bytesize}\r\n" +
           "Connection: close\r\n"

  socket.print "\r\n"
  socket.print response
  socket.close
end
```

Comment: `rails s` starts a local server

Comment: Can you give more information please?

Comment: In a terminal, navigate to the Rails project root folder, type `rails s` and press enter.

Comment: Thanks, i wasnt interested rails yet, i'll look up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do

```
ruby -run -e httpd -- . -p 8000
```

which will start server at port 8000 serving current directory (where server was started). Thus you could place all your HTML pages inside a folder and start server from there.

Answer (score 5):

Other people think you just want to **start** a web server, maybe your question is **how to write a web server in ruby**.
This is a [good introduction](https://github.com/planetruby/awesome-webservers) on ruby web servers and it contains an example shows how to build a sample http server,  cite here for you:

```
require 'socket'
server = TCPServer.new 80

loop do
  # step 1) accept incoming connection
  socket = server.accept

  # step 2) print the request headers (separated by a blank line e.g. \r\n)
  puts line = socket.readline  until line == "\r\n"

  # step 3) send response

  html = "<html>\r\n"+
         "<h1>Hello, World!</h1>\r\n"+
         "</html>"

  socket.write "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n" +
               "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n" +
               "Content-Length: #{html.bytesize}\r\n"

  socket.write "\r\n"  # write a blank line to separate headers from the html doc
  socket.write html    # write out the html doc

  # step 4) close the socket, terminating the connection
  socket.close
end
```

Start it by running ruby this_file.rb, and test with a get method.

Comment: This definitely should be the accepted answer. It looks like OP is just introducing themselves to web stuff using ruby. Rails is a whole different beast, it's a little unnerving that the other answers/comments equate ruby with rails.

Answer (score -1):

You can use rack to do this,http://rack.github.io/, and the rails is also base on the rack.

Answer (score -2):

All you have to do is bring up your console and type  `rails server`

If you want to specify the port you can do  `rails server -p xxxx`